# How to take a substring of dataframes' names inside a list to replace all values in a column with this string?

Tags: r, string, list, dataframe

I have a long list of data frames. I want to get the last two strings of each data frame's name and use it to replace all values in certain column of each data frame within the list.

Toy example:

```
df_stringPA <- data.frame(name="MU",
                  col1= c(1,2,3),
                  col2= c(1,2,3))

df_stringCA <- data.frame(name="MU",
                  col1= c(1,2,3),
                  col2= c(1,2,3))

test_list <- list(PA=df_PA, CA=df_CA)

### desired output:

output_df_PA <- data.frame(name="PA",
                    col1= c(1,2,3),
                    col2= c(1,2,3))


output_df_CA <- data.frame(name="CA",
                    col1= c(1,2,3),
                    col2= c(1,2,3))
```

If I do it for an individual dataframe within the list, it works:

```
### doing it separately for each df within the list:
test_list$PA$name <- str_sub(deparse(substitute(test_list$PA)), start= -2)
```

But it is a long list, so doing it manually is not the best option. I have tested:

```
test_list <- lapply(test_list, function(x) x$name <- str_sub(deparse(substitute(x)), start= -2))
```

But I get the data frames within the list replaced by ']]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map`:

```r
 Map(function(a, b) {a$name <- b; a}, a = test_list, b = names(test_list))
$PA
  name col1 col2
1   PA    1    1
2   PA    2    2
3   PA    3    3

$CA
  name col1 col2
1   CA    1    1
2   CA    2    2
3   CA    3    3
```

Comment: Thanks @Allan,. This works fine when taking the entire name of the df within the list. The problem is that in my real dataset, the names of the dfs have other string that I want to exlclude, that's why I need to subset only the last two characters from the dfs' names. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @DiegoBrizuela do you already have all the data frames in a list, and is it a named list? If so, you can change `b = names(test_list)` in the above code to `b = substr(names(test_list), nchar(names(test_list)) - 1, nchar(names(test_list)))`

Comment: Yes, It is a named list where all data frames have long names, and I only need the last two characters of those names to be in the 'name' column. I think I need to edit my question again, because I am calling all the dataframes from a folder directly, and once the list object is created it already has the names, not the way I did in the toy example (naming the dfs as I create the list). Did I explain myself well?

Comment: @DiegoBrizuela yes - try my suggestion in the comment above

Comment: Thanks Allan, I just tested it in the actual dataset and it works perfectly. I was just trying to get my head around that last bit of code you added, what is nchar doing? and why -1 ? Thank you!

Comment: @DiegoBrizuela  `nchar(names(test_list))` gives you a vector of the number of characters in each name in the list. `nchar(names(test_list)) - 1` is just one less than that. Since `substr` is vectorized, that means that you will get the substring between the second last letter and last letter of each name.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `imap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
imap(test_list, ~ .x %>%
     mutate(name = .y))
$PA
  name col1 col2
1   PA    1    1
2   PA    2    2
3   PA    3    3

$CA
  name col1 col2
1   CA    1    1
2   CA    2    2
3   CA    3    3
```