# R: Set column name from dataframe name in list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a large list of dataframes like the following:

```
> head(lst)
$Set1
  ID Value
1  A     1
2  B     1
3  C     1

$Set2
  ID Value
1  A     1
2  D     1
3  E     1

$Set3
  ID Value
1  B     1
2  C     1
```

I would like to change the name of the column "Value" in each dataframe to be similar to the name of the dataframe, so that the list of dataframes looks like this:

```
> head(lst)
$Set1
  ID Set1
1  A     1
2  B     1
3  C     1

$Set2
  ID Set2
1  A     1
2  D     1
3  E     1

$Set3
  ID Set3
1  B     1
2  C     1
```

Can anyone think of a function that takes the name of each dataframe in the list and names the column accordingly? My original list has >400 dataframes, so I was hoping to automate this somehow. Sorry if this is a naive question, but I'm somehow stuck...

Thanks so much!

Here is an example of a list of dfs:

```
lst <- list(
  data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1, 1)),
  data.frame(ID = c("A", "D", "E"), Value = c(1, 1, 1)),
  data.frame(ID = c("B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1)),
  data.frame(ID = c("B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1)),
  data.frame(ID = c("B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1)),
  data.frame(ID = c("B", "C"), Value = c(1, 1)))
lst_names <- c("Set1", "Set2", "Set3", "Set4", "Set5","Set6")
names(lst) <- lst_names
```

Comment: An almost identical question was asked here eariler today - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71645690/how-to-take-a-substring-of-dataframes-names-inside-a-list-to-replace-all-values - does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue here is slightly simpler and the answer below by TimTeaFan is more efficient than the ones in the other thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the tidyverse we can use `purrr::imap` and `dplyr::rename`:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

lst %>% 
  imap(~ rename(.x, "{.y}" := Value))
#> $Set1
#>   ID Set1
#> 1  A    1
#> 2  B    1
#> 3  C    1
#> 
#> $Set2
#>   ID Set2
#> 1  A    1
#> 2  D    1
#> 3  E    1
#> 
#> $Set3
#>   ID Set3
#> 1  B    1
#> 2  C    1
#> 
#> $Set4
#>   ID Set4
#> 1  B    1
#> 2  C    1
#> 
#> $Set5
#>   ID Set5
#> 1  B    1
#> 2  C    1
#> 
#> $Set6
#>   ID Set6
#> 1  B    1
#> 2  C    1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm getting a could not find function ":=" error when I use this.

Comment: @r_user: In this case there seems to be a problem with your installed packages. {dplyr} depends on {rlang} from which the walrus operator `:=` comes from. Try reinstalling rlang.

Answer (score 2):

We can do,

```
lapply(
  names(lst), 
  function(x) setNames(lst[[x]], c(names(lst[[x]])[2], x))
)

[[1]]
  Value Set1
1     A    1
2     B    1
3     C    1

[[2]]
  Value Set2
1     A    1
2     D    1
3     E    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a function to change one column from a `datafram`

```
changeOneColumName <- function(df, oldName, newName){
  names(df)[names(df) == oldName] <- newName
  return(df)
}
```

And then, apply that function with the `Map`

```
Map(changeOneColumName, lst, oldName = 'Value', newName = names(lst))
```