# How would I set the name of a csv as column in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-os

I have 300 time series CSV's that do not contain IDs within them contained in a file called `all_dataframes`, and I am trying to go about adding a the name of the CSV as a column 'name'

For example,

df1.csv

```
date        value
2020-01-01  35
2020-01-02  40
2020-01-03  45
```

df2.csv

```
date        value
2022-03-01  15
2022-03-02  25
2022-03-03  20
```

The expected output would be:

df1.csv

```
name      date        value
df1       2020-01-01  35
df1       2020-01-02  40
df1       2020-01-03  45
```

df2.csv

```
name      date        value
df2       2022-03-01  15
df2       2022-03-02  25
df2       2022-03-03  20
```

I have tried using the below code as a way to do it, but it keeps throwing errors at me of `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file` even though I am in the correct working directory.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os.path

# Create a list of all CSV files in folder
files = glob.glob("*.csv")

# Creats list of filenames for appending to df
filenames = []

# Doing the thing
for csv in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    df['name'] = os.path.basename(csv)
    filenames.append(df)
```

Is there a more simple way to do this or should I try to fix the working directory error?

I found a recommended question very similar to this, however, it is in R and that's not a language I am comfortable with at this point.
[R: Set column name from dataframe name in list of dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647634/r-set-column-name-from-dataframe-name-in-list-of-dataframes)

Comment: You have probably an empty file? From the documentation: *Exception that is thrown in pd.read_csv (by both the C and Python engines) when empty data or header is encountered.*

Comment: "Is there a more simple way to do this " Your way seems pretty simple, not sure what you are expecting. In any case, your error seems totally unrelated

Answer (score 0):

You have probably an empty file? From the documentation:

> [**pandas.errors.EmptyDataError**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.errors.EmptyDataError.html)
>
> Exception that is thrown in pd.read_csv (by both the C and Python engines) when empty data or header is encountered

**Tip**: replace `glob` by `pathlib`:

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

for csvfile in pathlib.Path('.').glob('*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
    df.insert(0, 'name', csvfile.stem)
    df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)
```

Output:

```
>>> %cat df1.csv
name,date,value
df1,2020-01-01,35
df1,2020-01-02,40
df1,2020-01-03,45

>>> %cat df2.csv
name,date,value
df2,2022-03-01,15
df2,2022-03-02,25
df2,2022-03-03,20
```

Comment: This method seems like it should work, but I'm getting the error `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "WindowsPath") to str`

Comment: What is the line that raises this error?

Comment: It was `df.insert(0, 'name', csvfile.stem)` but I found a solution with the original code, thank you!

Comment: Did you find the empty file?

Comment: I did! However, I'm receiving a different error where Jupyter will not let me delete it. "Delete Failed Unhandled Error" and I cannot figure out a source of it. I'm assuming it might be a permissions problem, which is very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by throwing an error and skipping over the corrupt file with:

```
for csv in files:
    try:
        print(csv)
        df = pd.read_csv(csv)
        df['name'] = os.path.basename(csv)
        filenames.append(df)
    except:
        print("Error with" + csv)
```